# Парсинг сайта с помощью Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Появилась необходимость получить все ссылки со страницы сайта. Но суть проблемы заключается в том, что не получается получить ссылку с авито. 
Код нужного элемента выглядит так:

`<a class="c6e8ba5398--header--1fV2A"    href="https://www.cian.ru/rent/flat/217985486/" target="_blank">`

Код программы:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://www.cian.ru/snyat-2-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
links = []

for a in soup.findAll("a", href=True, target="_blank"):
    links.append(a)
print(links)
```

Мне нужно достать именно саму ссылку, а получается содержимое всего тега 'a'.

Comment: Добавляйте так: `links.append(a['href'])`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы получить атрибут тега, используется нотация с квадратными скобками `[]`.

Чтобы получить атрибут `href` тега `a`, Вы должны сделать следующее: `a['href']`.

***Пример:***

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://www.cian.ru/snyat-2-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/")
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

links = []
for a in soup.findAll("a", href=True, target="_blank"):
    links.append(a['href'])

print(links)
```